# Eclipse RCP - How to Add GEF Graphical Editor to Multipage Editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created my custom Graphical Editor.
Now, I want to have multipage editor with two tabs.
First Tab - Graphical editor
Second Tab - Some code I need to generate e.g. xml

Problem I am facing is adding Graphical Editor as page to my multipage editor.

addPage(index,editorPart) method of multipage editor accepts input as some class implementing IEditorPart.
But graphical editor doesn't do the same.

I need help in creating multipage editor which would have my Graphical Editor in it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your editor runs as a normal editor in the edit area then it must be derived from something that implements `IEditorPart`.

Comment: Yep, GraphicalEditor does implement EditorPart. Thanks